# Restoring android libGLES.so to default

Tags: android, opengl-es, adb, egl

I've recently been trying to get the Mali Graphics Debugger program working but, found that, unfortunately, it not only doesn't work with my device but also insisted on installing a new alternative to 'libGLES.so' which causes problems on my device (display goes black at inopportune times)

Logging in to my phone via adb I can see that the mali debugger has created a new symbolic link to their library, which looks like this:

```
shell@klte:/system/lib/egl $ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- root     root           23 2015-01-07 12:20 egl.cfg
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2018-07-19 11:12 libGLES -> /system/lib/egl/libGLES_mgd.so
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              2018-07-19 11:12 libGLES.so -> /system/lib/egl/libGLES_mgd.so
-rwxrwxrwx root     sdcard_r 10963712 2018-07-19 11:12 libGLES_mgd.so
```

The original library, I assume, is found here:

```
127|shell@klte:/system/lib/egl $ ls -l /vendor/lib/egl/
-rw-r--r-- root     root        42228 2015-01-07 12:20 eglsubAndroid.so
-rw-r--r-- root     root       161908 2014-01-01 14:31 libEGL_adreno.so
-rw-r--r-- root     root       206236 2015-01-07 12:20 libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
-rw-r--r-- root     root      1284548 2014-01-01 14:31 libGLESv2_adreno.so
-rw-r--r-- root     root       616124 2015-01-07 12:20 libq3dtools_adreno.so
```

I cannot find any way within the mali debugging tool to restore the old linkages, although that seems surprising to me (if anybody could point out such a feature, that'd save me doing this another way)

I imagine that what I ought to do is remove those symbolic links and create new ones (or rather,restore old ones) that point to the libraries in the vendor library.

My questions are therefore: 
a.) Am I correct in the above assumption: will that solve my problem, without causing other problems and
b.) how can I get adb to use a writable filesystem so that I can create those symbolic links?

Comment: Panic over - option to uninstall library was on a right click context menu within Mali Graphics Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Within mali graphics debugger's device manager, you can uninstall the offending library using a right click context menu:

[image]

I feel a bit foolish for not spotting that earlier but I'll leave this up here in case some other dev makes the same mistake.